# apply a template to a column of datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mvvm

I'm using `MVVM` and I want to apply a template to a specific column of my datagrid.

I create Machine class which have Name, costs,  properties.

I create also Operation Class which have Name porperty, ExecutiveMachine property (Type : Machine)
When I use itemsSource to display my list of opertations, I see the path of my machines whereas I want to display their name.
I added `DataGridTemplateColumn` but now, I have machine column twice (one correct, and the other is incorrect)

Actually my code is :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Operations}" Name="datagridOperation" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionMode="Single" MinColumnWidth="80" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" RowBackground="DimGray" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF3E3E3E" AlternationCount="1" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="UpdateOperationComboBox">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Machine" CanUserSort="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ExecutiveMachine.Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

My first idea was to add manually `DataGridColumns`. I tried it but when a do it i have twice all my columns and if I delete `ItemsSource` property of my `DataGrid` I have only once but the three columns become empty.
If my idea is good, how can I bind this `ItemsSource` ?

Comment: Insert columns manually and set `DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add you columns manually then you need to switch off [`AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) against your `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Operations}" 
    Name="datagridOperation"
    ...
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

**EDIT**

To manually define sorting path for any `DataGridColumn` you can specify [`DataGridColumn.SortMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Machine" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="SortPropertyName">
```

Comment: thanks, it works.... But now, how can I sort elements by name when I click on column header ?
I added `CanUserSort="True"` and that is not working

Comment: It stopped working on all columns or just on this one?

Comment: I can only resize the width...
All manually added column can't be sorted when I click on the header.
But, autoGenerateColums can be sorted on click

Comment: do you use `DataGridTemplateColumn` for all manually added columns or you use also `DataGridTextColumn` and/or `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` because they should sort out sorting automatically for `DataGridTemplateColumn` check my edit

Comment: I'm using `DataGridTemplateColumn`... `<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Machine" CanUserSort="True">
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                         
         <Label Content="{Binding Path=ExecutiveMachine.Name}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>`

Comment: Check my edit. Use `SortMemberPath` and specify property name to sort by

Comment: It works.... thanks a lot....
but i have a last question.. sorrry....
Why it sorts as `m1, m10, m11, m12,m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9`
whereas `m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12` OR `m12, m11, m10, m9,...m1`

**EDIT : ** it's because of ACSI table but, can I solve it

Comment: Because property is a string and will be sorted alphabetically and since 1 is before 2 so m10 is before m2, m3 and so on. But, if you want, you can create another, `int` property that would extract number from that string and set `SortMemberPath` to new property. So you can display one value and sort by another in the same column