# Bind to one column of datagrid and apply style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, styles

I have a WPF datagrid which is bound to a datatable using MVVM. There are several columns in this datatable, one of which is a nullable boolean. When the datagrid is rendered, the boolean column (containing mostly nulls) shows block-filled check boxes and looks awful:

Current: [image: Nullable text box column]        Desired: [image: Hidden check boxes]

I would like to add a style to this column to hide all checkboxes if the value is null.
This question is similar to [apply a template to a column of datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014217/apply-a-template-to-a-column-of-datagrid), however I cannot manually define every column in the XAML as the number and positions of the columns in the bound datatable can change.

My datatable is defined in the view model as:

```
    public DataTable Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set
        {
            data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }
```

and is set in the class constructor by calling a SQL stored procedure that returns a datatable. This stored procedure can be different depending on usage so will produce different datatables at different times.

Currently, I have this code:

```
          <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Paid}" Header="Paid?">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

However, adding this code has changed my datagrid columns from:
[image: Headers before change]

and has simply added a new checkbox column to the start of the grid:
[image: Headers after change]

The newly added column does show the desired check box effect (only checkboxes with a value shown) however the original 'Paid' column is untouched.

Could somebody please let me know how to bind my style to this one column only?

Comment: Is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true on the DataGrid? If not, can you please post all your `DataGrid.Columns` definitions?

Comment: This is my entire datagrid definition. There are no other datagrid.columns definitions because the grid takes it from the itemsource 'Data' (I will include the definition for this table in the view model - It's just a SQL call) AutoGenerateColumns is not set which i believe means it's defaulted to false?

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns` is by default `true`.

Comment: A workaround could be to create a new Class (enum) with 3 states, true, false and undefined and bind to that. It seems like the binding will turn the nullbool to true ;/

Comment: Possible intermediate solution--create an IValueConverter that converts nulls from the view model to falses in the UI.  The conversion back would work, as the property is being set and therefore no longer null.   You wouldn't be able to null out the column, but I don't know if that's a requirement or not.

Comment: That's a great idea! Just to be a complete dunce... where should I use the converter in the xaml? - not being able to list the columns makes it really difficult!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true which means that the `DataGrid` will first use your custom column definitions and then append it's own definitions to the `DataGrid` which is why you get the first "Paid?" column and then the rest of the automatically generated columns.

To get the layout that you want, you could to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` and provide all the definitions of the columns.

Otherwise, try assigning a local resource to the `DataGrid` to style all `DataGridCheckBoxColumns` with your custom `ElementStyle`. Also note that you could simply set the `IsThreeState` property to `false` on the column as well which should stop the `{x:Null}` state appearing.

**Update:**

Looking deeper into this, there may be an issue with styling the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`. You will need to handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and set the `ElementStyle` within the handler.

Similar to:

```
void grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Column is DataGridCheckBoxColumn)
    {
        var checkBoxColumn = e.Column as DataGridCheckBoxColumn;
        var resource =     Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(CheckBox));
        checkBoxColumn.ElementStyle = resource as Style;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/06/wpfs-datagridcheckboxcolumn-elementstyle-uses-a-wrong-default-value/

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me as I cannot manually provide the definitions for every column. I suppose I will need AutoGenerateColumns to stay true so that the columns can be picked up from the database.

Comment: Please check the update edits - the assumption made is that all the `DataGridCheckBoxColumns` in this grid would need to display this behaviour (no 3rd state).

Comment: Local resource might work - I'll try it, sadly i've already tried setting IsThreeState to false and it's had no effect. I'll see what I can do with local resource. Thanks

Comment: I've got myself a local resource style based on checkbox. However I'm having some trouble placing it in the datagrid:

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

This has the same effect as before. Haven't managed to find anything online to do it. Could you please point me in the right direction? Sorry to keep asking.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and again for looking into this further for me. The updated answer absolutely did the trick. I had found this on my searches but was reluctant to break the MVVM. Seems like it's the only way though.
Thankyou again for all your help :)